# $.ajax({ }) Post request to a PHP file is returning a null value

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I have been looking at this problem for quite a while now and cannot seem to figure out why I keep receiving null after my $.ajax function is called.I input an associative array that contains my method name and then call my method in PHP to return a j son string back to the front end. I receive null when I call alert in my java script. Here is my code

Java script:

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
     var data = {};
     data["Method"] = "test";
     $.ajax({

            url:"test.php/test",
            data: data,
            type:"POST",
            contentType:"application/json",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){

            alert(data);

            },
            error:function(data, textStatus, error)
            {

            }
     });
});
```

PHP:

```
   <?

    //require_once("database.php");

    class methods
    {
      function __contructor()
      {
        if(isset($_POST["Method"]))
        {
              $function = $_POST["Method"];
              call_user_func($function);
        }
        else
        {
              echo "{\"status\":\"false\"}";
        }
     }

      function test()
      {
            $json = array( 
            "kyle" => "broflowksi",
            "eric" => "cartman",
            "stan" => "marsh"
             );
            echo json_encode($json);
      }

   }

     $method = new methods();

   ?>
```

Comment: As an aside, you can create your `data` object in one step: `var data = { Method : "test" };` - or even include that object directly within the Ajax call with `data : { Method : "test" }`.

Comment: I really don't like the procedure with call_user_func() from an unfiltered `$_POST` value. Personally I'd either make a list of allowed functions or make a hash table of anonymous functions of which to call. In the current state you are very vulnerable to attacks, especially if you allow users to pass arguments as well.

Comment: Can we see your mod_rewrite as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's simply a typo in your class constructor method, it should be

```
function __construct()
```

One other thing to keep in mind is that I'm not sure you should be setting the contentType to json, as that variable is for what you're sending... not what you're receiving. 
So if you end up having a situation where the post variables are being stripped, try and remove the contentType form your ajax call.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to call is an instance method. Call it this way:

```
if(isset($_POST["Method"]))
{
      $function = $_POST["Method"];
      $method = new ReflectionMethod('methods', $function);
      $method->invoke($this);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response that function was the problem. I was confused where you wanted me to place that case statement but I figured it out. Thank You

Comment: I tried your invoke method and I received this error. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Non-object passed to Invoke()

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing a content-type header before sending the output,

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Comment: This doesn't hurt but it isn't the reason why he gets no output.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `echo` in `test` method. You are calling

```
 call_user_func($function);
```

and your `$function` is not `returning` but `echoing`, .i.e

```
function test() {
        $json = array( 
        "kyle" => "broflowksi",
        "eric" => "cartman",
        "stan" => "marsh"
         );
        echo json_encode($json);          // This line should be returning
}
```

I had dealt with similar issue earlier with a php function call (not in ajax particular).to catch.

Comment: It is an AJAX request. It *should* be `echo`ing.

Comment: I guess `echo` will work if you are assinging the value from a function call to a variable. But the case here is different. It's in the parameter and `echo` I suppose is getting lost somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @BotondBalázs unless `call_user_func` does some unexpected magic (such as discarding the output buffer and echoing the return value instead), `return`ing the user output won't help.

Comment: -1 anything returned from `$function` will be discarded by the caller.

Comment: @BotondBalázs we are. Should I delete my comment?